# Upload a file in segments using html5 and JSF

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-1.2

I'm trying to upload a file in segments, using the HTML5 File API (after finding out the file upload components from RichFaces and PrimeFaces are not the best fit for my need). I have followed the steps hinted in this question:

[uploading a file in chunks using html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853467/uploading-a-file-in-chunks-using-html5)

However I need to do it with JSF 1.2 instead of PHP, which means (I think):

```
xhr.open("POST", "upload.xhtml");
```

instead of

```
xhr.open("POST", "upload.php");
```

Is there a way to do that? How do I tell JSF to get the file segments to process them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't submit a non-JSF POST request to a JSF page. You need to homegrow a custom servlet for non-JSF POST requests. You can find a concrete example of such a servlet in this answer on a closely related question: [HTML5 File Upload to Java Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114087/html5-file-upload-to-java-servlet/7136219#7136219).

Comment: Nice example, but when trying to run the line  `xhr.open("POST", "uploadServlet", false);`, the servlet isn't being called.

Comment: Checking browser's JS console and HTTP traffic monitor should give clues. Perhaps it returned a 404 simply because either URL is completely wrong or the servlet isn't properly mapped.

Comment: You were right, I had to add a `#{request.contextPath}` first. How do I notify back the html page the result of the file process once the servlet finishes its job, for example updating a div with a "SUCESS" or "ERROR" message?

Comment: The `xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);` part in the example does that with `uploadComplete()` function.

Answer (score 0):

for recovery uploaded file from servlet in primfaces (primfaces 5 is my versión), use this code

```
   @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
    HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        FileItem fi;
        try {
             MultipartRequest sReq = (MultipartRequest)request;
             fi = sReq.getFileItem("file");

         } catch (Exception e) {
             throw new ServletException("ERROR: ", e);
         }

        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        if(fi != null)
        {
            response.getWriter().write(" Fichero capturado correctamente "); 
        }
        else
        {
            response.getWriter().write(" Se ha producido algún fallor ");       
        }
    }
```

Quid of the question is:

```
     MultipartRequest sReq = (MultipartRequest)request;
     fi = sReq.getFileItem("file");
```

I hope that you can use my solution.