# Entity too large Error

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm having a little trouble with my service. It does not support a large amount of data, and I have to send an image encoded in base64 for it.
The service configuration is like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "create", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
WSResult<WebService.Model.Order> create(WSOrderCreateParams paramsData);
```

And the web.config has this configurations:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1000000000"/>
<system.web>
...
<service.serviceModel>
...
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WebHttpEndpointBinding"
      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
...
</service.serviceModel>
...
<services>
  <service name="WebService.ws.Order">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WebService.ws.IOrder"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried breaking the file up into chunks, and have the web service put them back together?

Comment: On your `<service>`, try adding `bindingConfiguration="WebHttpEndpointBinding"`

Comment: @javisrk, how can I do that?

Comment: @kei, tried it, but didn't work

Comment: There's an example of using the HTML5 file API to upload chunks at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853467/uploading-a-file-in-chunks-using-html5 - the server example is PHP, but the client example is standard javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it, by the web config. This is how the Web.config is now:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1000000000"/>
<system.web>
    ...
<service.serviceModel>
  ...
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WebHttpEndpointBinding"
      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
  ...
</service.serviceModel>
    ...
<services>
  <service name="WebService.ws.Order">
    <endpoint address="" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpEndpointBinding" behaviorConfiguration="Web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WebService.ws.IOrder"/>
  </service>
</services>
...
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
  <serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="2147483647" />
</system.webServer>
```

I've added the bindingConfiguration at the service, like @kei said, and

```
<serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="2147483647" />
```

at system.webServer. The default pool of IIS won't let you use the uploadReadAheadSize, so you have to go on : IIS Manager > Configurations Editor > Section: system.webServer/serverRuntime > Unlock Section. Doing this, it should work :)