# how to upload chunks of file via javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

How can i upload a file by using HTML and JavaScript to chunk the file, collect the chunks at the server side using AJAX and PHP and upload it when the file is complete

Answer (score 0):

You can use some plugins to do that, some ajax uploaders, but I think that this answer can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7897620/4627253