# How can I dynamically animate an AJAX loading bar until it reaches 100%?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is a follow up question from my previous one ["How do I measure a loading time of an AJAX request and display a loading panel?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899183/how-do-i-measure-a-loading-time-of-an-ajax-request-and-display-a-loading-panel). Now I am wondering how will I suppose to display an animated loading bar/panel like this:

[image]

And what I mean is that an actual moving panel from 0% to 100%. I have here a bit of code to begin the discussion. I'm implementing a tutorial loading from this wonderful [site](http://www.kpozin.net/ajaxprogress).

```
    $("#connection").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //show_loading();
        $.ajax({
            url: "./home/connect",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json', 
            progress: function(jqXHR, progressEvent) {
                if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
                    console.log("Loaded " + (Math.round(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100)) + "%");
                } else {
                    console.log("Loading...");
                }
            },
            success : function(data) {
                //hide_loading();
                Materialize.toast(data.db_connect, 4000, 'rounded green');
            },
        });
    });
```

The problem with this code is that it displays 100% in the console the moment it reaches to 100% and not live ( showing the actual counting from 0 - 100 ).

[image]

Comment: As best I know, the Ajax progress only works for actual data transfer where there are significant enough bytes to transfer that the progress indicator is meaningful about the time to upload or download.  The progress event does not cover the time of the ajax response from the server.

Comment: lets just say i have a function that counts for 5 seconds, how will i sync the time and the progress bar to reach 100% when timer reach 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `progress` function in the official docs but I found this code [here](http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/):

```
$.ajax({
    url: path,
    xhrFields: {
        onprogress: function (e) {
            if (e.lengthComputable) {
                console.log(e.loaded / e.total * 100 + '%');
            }
        }
    },
    success: function (response) {

    }
});
```

Comment: yeah they are behaving the same. its still just showing my the 100% and not the dynamic counting. @ShanShan

Comment: quick question though, can the console render live data feeds? like what we are doing?

Comment: Yes, the console works all the time. I think your server just doens't send the size of the response so a progress is not computable. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502943/jquery-ajax-progress-via-xhr

Comment: im pretty sure its computable. otherwise it will just log `Loading...`.